# Django - Models does not call content of database

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a class in the `models.py` containing the information of articles I want to insert in a website

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse 

class Article(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing an article.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the article')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=100000)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a detail record for this article.
        """
        return reverse('article-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

After that, I have inserted an article using the admin panel of Django and saved it.

Then, I have created the `index.html` shown below calling the articles in the database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}{% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
  {% block sidebar %}<!-- insert default navigation text for every page -->{% endblock %}
  {% block content %}<!-- default content text (typically empty) -->
  <!-- Articles -->
  <div class="articles">
    <h1>Titolo: {{ article.title }}</h1>

    <p><strong>Autori:</strong> {{ article.authors }}</p>
    <p><strong>Riepilogo:</strong> {{ article.summary }}</p>
    <p><strong>Testo:</strong> {{ article.content }}</p>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

But the article is not shown despite being in the database (see prints below)

[image: Print of output]

**EDIT1**: inserted views.py as requested

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """
    View function for home page of site.
    """

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
    )
```

Comment: Please update your question with `views.py` as well.

Comment: You need to pass render's context, see example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not including any articls in your template context:

```
return render(
    request,
    'index.html',
)
```

You could include the articles in the template context with:

```
articles = Article.objects.all()
return render(
    request,
    'index.html',
    {'articles': articles}
)
```

Then in the template you need to loop through the articles.

```
<!-- Articles -->
<div class="articles">
  {% for article in articles %}
  <h1>Titolo: {{ article.title }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Autori:</strong> {{ article.authors }}</p>
  <p><strong>Riepilogo:</strong> {{ article.summary }}</p>
  <p><strong>Testo:</strong> {{ article.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to post a similar answer but you were faster. Anyways judging from the definition of OP's method `Article.def get_absolute_url(self)` and the template, only one article should be displayed and it's id is included in request.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo the view is `def index(request):` so I assumed that the OP would want to display all articles for this view.

Comment: Well, it was confusing because of lack of `for` loop in original template, but apparently you are right, since the answer is accepted.